# Is there a way to hack your Facebook account back?

Tags: password-cracking, facebook

I think that from title it's pretty obvious what I'm trying to do. My Facebook account has been hacked, as it's using e-mail from whom I've forgotten password I can't get it back. I'm not using this e-mail anymore and is not important to me, while Facebook account is. There were no 2FA on account so that's not possible either.

Can someone help me with retrieving my account back? There are a lot of important information on it, not just personal but work-related also. Can I hack it back?? I've gotten to the point where I'm losing my mind.

Comment: the keyword you should look for is not 'password-cracking' but 'social engineering'.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course it is *possible*; an easy example is that the current owner has a password, and so if you try every single password in existence you will eventually get the right one.

This is, however, not a feasible method, nor a legal one.  Your best bet is to go through Facebook's account recovery procedures, and to take this as a lesson to make sure you've covered basic account security precautions on any account you deem important, like having the correct email set up for password recovery.

Comment: As you can guess, I've already tried Facebook's account recovery and didn't accomplish anything. That's why I'm posting here...

Comment: Please refer to my [previous question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/222351/how-to-hack-facebook-twitter-instagram-whatsapp)

Comment: @JohnZhau Can I talk to you about your question? Thanks.

Comment: Sure you can. It was more of an awareness article than a good security.SE question though.